Unity Runtime generated normal map appears different than editor created normal map
I am attempting to import a jpg normal map at runtime and apply it to a material. The issue is that the material appears wrong compared to using a editor imported normal map. After importing the jpeg, my normal map conversion function looks like this
            Texture2D convertedNormalMap = new Texture2D(source.width, source.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true, true);

            Color32[] cols = source.GetPixels32(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++)
            {
                cols[i].a = cols[i].r;
                cols[i].r = 255; // Color32 uses a byte per component, so 255 == 1.0
                cols[i].b = 255;
            }
            convertedNormalMap.SetPixels32(cols, 0);
            convertedNormalMap.Apply();
            return convertedNormalMap;


Here are the results for a simple metalic material type. Her is my version using runtime normal map :

here is correct version using editor imported normal map with “Texture type” set to “Normal map” in unity editor:

The weird thing is that when inspecting the runtime normal map, it appears to look the same as the unity imported one. Below is the comparison. The left is the runtime and the right is editor

any idea why the weird results?

cols[i].r = 255; ? I don't think this can genreate the color of the screenshot.

@shingo I am using the method from this post https://forum.unity.com/threads/runtime-normal-map-formats.1192042/

The 2nd image is the result of his code generation.

@shingo The left is the runtime generation (from the above forum post).
